# How create nhibernate criteria with inlaid terms in algorithm?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

For example:

```
var Ex1 = Expression.Eq("DocAttrId", new decimal(-2));
var Ex2 = Expression.Eq("RowPos", new decimal(1));
var Ex3 = Expression.Eq("DocAttrId", new decimal(105510));
var Ex4 = Expression.Eq("DocAttrId", new decimal(-1));
var ExGroup1 = (Ex1 || Ex2);
var ExGroup2 = (Ex3 && ExGroup1);
var ExGroup3 = (Ex4 || ExGroup2);
_criteria.Add(ExGroup3);
```

Can I create a algorithm by build a criteria if I have all Ex1...Ex4 expression in a list or array???

Comment: Off topic, but you don't need to instantiate decimals like that: "-2" will work just fine on its own

Comment: how simply add 'and' 'or' condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var expressions = new[] {
    Expression.Eq("DocAttrId", new decimal(-2)),
    Expression.Eq("RowPos", new decimal(1)),
    Expression.Eq("DocAttrId", new decimal(105510)),
    Expression.Eq("DocAttrId", new decimal(-1)),
}

var ExGroup1 = Expression.Or(expressions[0], expressions[1]);
var ExGroup2 = Expression.And(expressions[2], ExGroup1);
var ExGroup3 = Expression.Or(expressions[3], ExGroup2);
_criteria.Add(ExGroup3);
```